# SQL Server finding maximum query

Tags: sql, sql-server

me being a humble sql beginner, I have a question: let's say I have two tables:  Items, and People(to whom an item is sold). Is there any way in SQL to produce a query to show data of a person who bought the most items, and the ammount of items he or she bought?

my creates are:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    (other data)
);

CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
   (other stuff....)
   bought_by INT REFERENCES PEOPLE
);
```

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just group by `bought_by` from `ITEMS` table, sort the result descending by the count and get the top record:

```
select top 1 bought_by, count(*)
from ITEMS
group by bought_by
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this query can help you too, if you need more people data/info:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PEOPLE.*, COUNT(ITEMS.*) AMOUNT FROM PEOPLE 
    JOIN ITEMS ON PEOPLE.ID = ITEMS.bought_by
GROUP BY PEOPLE.ID, PEOPLE.OtherFieldsInPeopleTable 
ORDER BY COUNT(ITEMS.*) DESC
```